# Does Getter and Setter in ASP.MVC can instantiate an object?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, oop, razor, asp.net-core-tag-helpers

From [Microsoft MVC doc, related to Authoring Tag Helpers](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/views/tag-helpers/authoring), I can read this:

```
using System;

namespace AuthoringTagHelpers.Models
{
    public class WebsiteContext
    {
        public Version Version { get; set; }
        public int CopyrightYear { get; set; }
        public bool Approved { get; set; }
        public int TagsToShow { get; set; }
    }
}
```

and this:

```
using System;
using AuthoringTagHelpers.Models;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Razor.TagHelpers;

namespace AuthoringTagHelpers.TagHelpers
{
    public class WebsiteInformationTagHelper : TagHelper
    {
        public WebsiteContext Info { get; set; }

      public override void Process(TagHelperContext context, TagHelperOutput output)
      {
         output.TagName = "section";
         output.Content.SetHtmlContent(
             $@"<ul><li><strong>Version:</strong> {Info.Version}</li>
            <li><strong>Copyright Year:</strong> {Info.CopyrightYear}</li>
            <li><strong>Approved:</strong> {Info.Approved}</li>
           <li><strong>Number of tags to show:</strong> {Info.TagsToShow}</li></ul>");
         output.TagMode = TagMode.StartTagAndEndTag;
      }
   }
}
```

I never saw this kind of code before, where **public WebsiteContext Info { get; set; }** can automagically instantiate an object???

How it works? Is there any documentation on it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer is in the [document you linked](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/views/tag-helpers/authoring):

> **Note**
>
> In the Razor markup shown below:

```
<website-information info="new WebsiteContext {
                                Version = new Version(1, 3),
                                CopyrightYear = 1638,
                                Approved = true,
                                TagsToShow = 131 }" />
```

> Razor knows the info attribute is a class, not a string, and you want to write C# code. Any non-string tag helper attribute should be written without the @ character.

The tag helper itself doesn't know how to instantiate the instance. You have to do it manually in the Razor markup or set it to a default value in the property declaration or class constructor in order for it to be non-null. Here is an example of setting the instance in the property declaration.

```
public WebsiteContext { get; set; } = new WebSiteContext 
{ 
    Version = new Version(1, 3),
    CopyrightYear = 1638,
    Approved = true,
    TagsToShow = 131
};
```

Answer (score 0):

`public WebsiteContext Info { get; set; }` is not instantiating anything here. If you call the following code:

`var websiteInformationTagHelper = new WebsiteInformationTagHelper();`

then `websiteInformationTagHelper.Info` will be equal to `null`

Note, that it is now possible in c# to assign default values like the following which is a little bit different than what you are wondering about:
`public WebsiteContext Info { get; set; } = new WebsiteContext()`

Answer (score -1):

Not automatically, but yes. The get and set keywords are shorthand for methods that are called after the property is accessed (get) or assigned to (set). You can add a body with a regular code block:

```
get { return _backingField; }
set { _backingField = value; }
```

The value keyword represents the value being assigned to the property and you can do most things in those blocks, same as any method, including instantiating an object.

Microsoft documentation - Auto implemented properties:
[learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/auto-implemented-properties](http://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/auto-implemented-properties)

If you're referring to instantiating the parent object, that I don't believe makes sense.